# Writing equations in point slope form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Harvey rides his bike at an
average speed of 12 miles per hour. In
other words, he rides 12 miles in 1 hour,
24 miles in 2 hours, and so on. Let h be
the number of hours he rides and d be
distance traveled. Write the equation for
the relationship between distance and
time in point-slope form

The perimeter of a square
varies directly with the side length. The
point-slope form of the equation for this
function is y - 4 = 4(x - 1). Write the
equation in standard form

Geoff paddles his canoe at
an average speed of 3.5 miles per hour.
After 5 hours of canoeing, Geoff has
traveled 18 miles. Write an equation in
the point-slope form to find the total
distance y for any number of hours x

Comment: If this OP is not trying to get solutions to three unrelated questions from a homework, who is?

Answer (score 3):

*I will not do your work for you. However, it helps to get started by knowing clearly what you need to know and what you need to do to solve problems like this:*

In each question, you are asked to represent the ***relationship*** between *two variables*: how one can be expressed as a function of the other, and you need to establish how one changes with respect to the other.

If you're confused about the difference between the various forms (representations) of an equation (of a line), recall that:

- the ***point-slope form*** for the equation of a line is formatted like this: $(y - y_0) = m(x - x_0)$: 
  $m$ = slope, $(x_0, y_0)$ is a particular point on the line.
- the ***standard form*** of an equation of a line is: $ax + by = c$.
- the ***slope-intercept form*** for the equation of a line is $y = mx + b$, again, with $m$ being slope, and $b$ represents the "$y$-intercept": the value of $y$ when $x = 0.$

*You should become familiar with each form*, because depending on the information you are given, one particular form may be needed. (E.g., if you're given a point on a line, and can determine the slope of a line, then point-slope form comes in handy!)

Once you have an equation in one form, then transitioning from one form to another requires some very basic algebra!

---

To get you started:

1. What is your slope $m$ here? $\dfrac{\text{(Change in distance)}}{\text{(change in time)}} = m$.

From what you're given:

$\quad 12 = 12\cdot 1$
$\quad 24 = 12 \cdot 2$

continuing...

$\quad 36 = 12 \cdot 3$

$\quad\quad\;\;\vdots$

$\quad \;d = 12 \cdot h$

What does $12$ represent? This equation gives you the relation between $d$: distance traveled, and $h$: hours spent traveling. Now, simply put it in point-slope form, where $d$ is your "y" and $h$ is your "x": what is your starting point $(x_0, y_0)$?

---

Answer (score 2):

Is this your homework? At least try to post some of your work if it is. I'm not here to do your homework for you.

Point slope form for an equation uses the following format: $y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$

Standard form is: $Ax + By = C$

So if you're given an equation in slope-intercept form, $y = mx + b$, and you want to write it in standard form, move both the variables x and y to the left hand side.

Example: Slope intercept form $y = 2x - 6$ would be
$2 x - y = 6$ in standard form.